# Scrape HTML table to Google Chart via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to take an HTML table on a page, scrape that into a javascript array, and then use the google charts arraytodatatable function to use the resulting array as the source for the chart.  However, I'm having no success at all with it.  Below is the code for the function I am using (and I freely admit I'm fairly new at javascript but I have no errors in my console)

```
     var myTableArray = [];

    $("table#datatable tr").each(function() {
        var arrayOfThisRow = [];
        var tableHeader = $(this).find('th');
                if (tableHeader.length > 0) {
                    tableHeader.each(function() { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
            myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
                }
        var tableData = $(this).find('td');
            if (tableData.length > 0) {
                tableData.each(function() { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
            myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
} });
```

I found the code for this function on a stackoverflow post and modified it to also grab the headers of the table.

I get the error Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string from GoogleCharts when using this function.

It is entirely possible that I'm making this far too complicated, but any help is appreciated.